# How to get targeted age and gender from Facebook api (which I input when creating the adset) using python

Tags: python, api, facebook-graph-api

Is there a `Field` where I can get the targeted `age` and `gender` I did input when I was creating the **ad** in the first place using **Facebook-api**

```
 fields = [
            'campaign_id',
            'campaign_name',
            'account_currency'
          ...]
```

here I can get `campaign_id` and more info about the **campaign**, **adset** and **ad**

but I need to view the `age` and `gender` I was targeting while creating such **ad**

Answer (score 0):

There's a field called *demographic_distribution* which include the *genders* and the *age range*.

[Facebook doc](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/api)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but Could you provide more details, as I added the ```demographic_distribution``` inside ```Fields``` and resulted **error**:  demographic_distribution is not valid for fields param.